# Why "Analyze designer files" is the default for StyleCop?

Tags: c#, coding-style, code-analysis, windows-forms-designer, stylecop

StyleCop (4.7.14.0) has the setting "Analyze designer files" checked by default, and I'd like to know if there's any reasoning that would justify code style checks on a designer-generated file.

I understand that I can (and how to) disable it checking these files (I'm considering doing so), but the question is, why would it be the default to analyze these?

Aren't these files to be left alone? Why should we possibly try to make them StyleCop-compliant?

Comment: It is the Microsoft default.  Not yours, you can't do anything about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, I can change it and it will be stored in the `Settings.StyleCop` file, which would be used project-wide by anyone who checkouts the code, if that's what you mean. But I'd like to know if there was some reasoning behind it (as actually the `*.designer.cs` files aren't even StyleCop-compliant by default). It seems weird since the StyleCop devs surely know what happens if you leave it in the default (and the only discussions online seem to be about how to change that default, not why it's there in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

It can be desirable to hold generated code to the same standards as manually authored code.  Granted, this tends to be less important for pure "code style" issues like those covered by StyleCop than it is for "correctness" issues covered by tools like FxCop, but there can still be compelling reasons to check tool-generated code even for style issues.  e.g.:

1. If the tool that is generating the target code is a tool that one has authored, then it is not at all unusual to hold it to the same standards as manually written code.  This is, after all, a case where one does have full control over the contents and style of the generated code.
2. From a practical perspective, the tool could be removed or disabled at any time after generation of the code, in which case one ends up maintaining the code manually.  If style rules are being enforced to enhance readability and maintainability, allowing generated code to deviate too much from coding standards may not be desirable.

Comment: That sounds a likely scenario, that of checking the style of code generated by a tool we made ourselves. But as weird as it seems, the defaults are "Check `.designer.cs` files, but don't check `.generated.cs` files" (so it explicitely defaults not to check the style of the code your tool generated, and instead checks the Windows Forms Designer code).

Answer (score 0):

The main reason I can think of is that there's no absolute guarantee that a file with 'designer' in the name is only going automatically generated.

In these days of strong separation and the ability to use verbose and clear names, it's probably just edging on the sense of caution by default.

But I agree, if you're sure that they're always automatically generated then you shouldn't try and clean them up.

OTOH, my Dynamics CRM server generates a 12mb XRM reference file so I do tend to trim that one!

Comment: Well, the suffix must be `.Designer.cs`, so for example `WebDesigner.cs` would not be considered a designer file. I really doubt people would name files like `MyClass.Designer.cs`. Also, if you happen to have a file called just `Designer.cs`, it wouldn't have the full suffix, so I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be ignored either. I'm a bit curious about what do you do to clean up a 12 MB file, however.

Comment: One particular thing is removing class to CRM functions that I don't use although that's a fairly rare thing; the most important thing is to implement partial classes so I can split the functionality I need out into multiple files that individually don't clog up the compiler/resharper.